# How to connect to external and bridge network while using a specific IP address for a container in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, static-ip-address

I would like to achieve the following:
bridged network=> bridged with DHCP
bridged network=> internal 172.28.0.0/16

and I want a container to be connected to both of these networks while specifying a static IP for the internal network

Here is my attempt:

```
version: '3'
services:
  container1:
    container_name: container_1
    image: instance1
    networks:
      bridged_network1:
      bridged_network2:
        ipv4_address: 172.28.0.3


networks:
  bridged_network1:
    external: true
  bridged_network2:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.28.0.0/16
```

I receive the following error:

```
ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block collection
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 7, column 7
expected <block end>, but found '?'
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 8, column 7
```

Comment: Docker doesn't use DHCP internally, and there's not usually a reason to specify (or look up) the container-private IP addresses.  Does it help to delete all of the IP-address settings?  Which lines are lines 7 and 8?  Does a non-Docker-specific YAML validator help point out a more specific syntax problem?